# Something made all text really small - font and size settings, dpi seem ok

Tags: 13.04, nvidia, lubuntu, fonts, gui

After booting my pc up I noticed that the fonts on the login screen on my Lubuntu 13.04 are tiny. After logging in I noticed window titles being tiny and default font sizes in apps too such as Skype or LXterminal - unreadable even.
Fontsize was Ubuntu 11 as usual - changed everything to size 14 but it only changed titles and they are still smaller than they used to be.

Looking for others having similar problems, I found this command:

```
xdpyinfo | grep resolution
resolution:    59x60 dots per inch
```

which seems totally ok.

By the way Chromium is unaffected besides the title bar and menu.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And the culprit was...  nvidia-310.
Switching over to Nouveau fixed it and made everything superbig at 14 (as it should be). Changed fonts back to 11 and all is good.

Answer (score -2):

You'll never believe this but get its true...

I have spent MONTHS AND MONTHS AND MONTHS trying to fix this issue, happened with ubuntu lubuntu lubuntu xubuntu every ubuntu derivate out there, but didnt with manjaro. I liked manjaro but there was essential software which I needed which I couldn't find, so I neede to use a *buntu, but after installing nvidia drivers I had your issue. I tried all of them the newest the oldest the legacy ones, all did this weird text thing. I need nvidia proprietary drivers for usig opengl applications btw. A few hours ago I didn't have enough USB ports for something to plug in to my PC. I unplugged my webcam to make space. I rebooted my system for the other thing, and my ubuntu came up with the logo (normally has this weird code about frequencies and not being able to set them) so I thought okay. Logged in as normal and I saw that the fonts were back to normal!!! The applications also weren't in a kind of fallback mode which there were in as well! So unplug your webcam (if you have one) and see what happens! I've also heard unplugging any microphones you might have as well as they also cause this issue! Good luck :) you can also reinstall the nvidia drivers and have no issues....