# Lubuntu font size on any window is too small

Tags: lubuntu, fonts

I have recently install Lubuntu on a win7 PC using virtual box.
The problem I am facing now is the basic font of any application is very small for example :
[Firefox screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBBFA.png)

[Libre office screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wztcg.png)

As you can see the basic font is too small (see in the screen shots)
My screen resolution is : 1920x1080, changing it do not resolved the issue.

How do I resolve this issue

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/387808/something-made-all-text-really-small-font-and-size-settings-dpi-seem-ok try this out

Comment: in the solution provided user resolved by  Switching over to Nouveau from nvidia-310....but how do I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

How do you switch to Noveau from Nvidia you ask? Just open up synaptic from a terminal with `sudo synaptic` and look up noveau. Mark it for installation. Once you do it should replace your graphics driver on reboot. I don't use LXDE but there should be a font settings menu for it where you can change the font size system wide.

Comment: the font setting only allows changing font size of title bar, menu bar and icons not the basic font size